# Do javamail need email server running to send and recieve mails?

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, email-client

i'm new to JavaMail API, i struggled to enable port 25 in windows 7, but still it works only after installing hmailserver, i uninstalled hmailserver now and i'm trying to trigger a mail using JavaMail API but it could not connect smtp port 25.

My question is

```
     1. does javamail need email server running to trigger emails
     2. cant i run smtp server in localhost
     3. can java mail be used as smtp server?
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there needs to be a mail server, but it doesn't need to be **your** mail server.

You'll want to read the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#incservers).